# how to find process name from pid in java?

Tags: java

I know we can find processId by calling `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()`.

I need to know whether we can find process name from this ID. If there is not a platform independent solution, then please provide at least for linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what JPS does (sun.tools.jps.Jps):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java